# Женский род для профессий, заканчивающихся на «-лог»

Tags: грамотная-речь, лексика, род, профессии

Как будут в женском роде такие слова как *диетолог, психолог, биолог*?
Есть какое-нибудь правило для таких слов?
Как подчеркнуть, что речь идёт о женщине?

Comment: нет, у этих слов только "мужской" род, потому что это специальности. Но в разговорном языке иногда говорят биологичка и психологичка, если это школьный психолог.

Comment: Советую прочитать книгу И. Фуфаевой. Как называются женщины. Фиминитивы.

Answer (score 5):

Есть профессии, употребляющиеся исключительно в мужском роде, в том числе и по отношению к женщинам. Чаще всего истинно мужские названия носят профессии, связанные с **юриспруденцией, медициной, наукой** и **техникой**.

Подобные профессии легко распознать по окончаниям: ***-ор, -ер, -лог, -граф, -вед.***
Примеры: инженер, копирайтер, директор, диктор, режиссер, диспетчер, редактор, автор, конструктор, дизайнер, **офтальмолог, стоматолог, геолог, психолог**, типограф, фотограф, языковед, правовед.

Все указанные вами слова имеют только мужской род (то есть феминитивов для них нет).
Если есть сомнения, то название профессии всегда можно проверить в словарях:
[**диетолог**](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3), -а; ***м.*** Врач — специалист по диетологии;
**радист**, -а; ***м.*** Специалист по приёму и передаче звуковых сигналов, сообщений по радио. **<Радистка**, -и; ***мн. род.*** -ток, ***дат.*** -ткам; ***ж.***

> В разговорной речи явно наметилась тенденция выражать отнесение подобных слов к лицам женского пола синтаксически, главным образом путем постановки сказуемого в форме женского рода, если в функции-подлежащего выступает одно из слов указанной группы, например: ***депутат принимала** избирателей, **мастер спорта установила** новый рекорд, **врач-педиатр провела** прием.* Эта форма смыслового согласования получила широкое распространение и в периодической печати, например: *Двое суток **чабан** без пищи, при 35-градусном морозе **берегла** отару, **Премьер-министр** Великобритании **провела** консультации* (о Маргарет Тэтчер).

Подробнее — здесь:
[§ 148. Род названий лиц женского пола по профессии, должности и т. д.](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/57.htm#%D0%B7_03);
[Феминитивы: инструкция по применению](https://te-st.org/2021/03/08/feminitive-instruction/).

Comment: Кстати говоря, про чехарду с гендерами и феминитивами. Гендер - это же не пол, а как раз род. Не нужно путать пол и род, это разные вещи. То что название вещи или явления в женском роде или среднем, вообще не имеет отношения к полу. Расческа - не становится женщиной, как и гребень не становится мужчиной, кайло - не становится транссексуалом. И проблема в том, что пересекли семантику слов гендер и секс. В русском это вообще так не работает. Женский урок - урок мужской род, но пола у урока нет, был бы пол, женский урок - было бы вообще белиберда. Меч - мужской род, сабля шашка - женский.

Comment: Однако что меч, что сабля - это оружие, то есть оно, по роду. Так что тут вообще не нужно образовывать женские или мужские формы, род слова - это вообще не о том. Ни какой принадлежности к мужчинам или женщинам род слова не имеет. Иначе придется всех в правах уравнивать и производить феминитивы от меч - меча, и от сабля мускулитивы - сабель. Короче будет полная шизофрения.

Comment: Э-э... Не поняла — зачем нам тут гребень, меч, кайло? Феминитив — это существительное **женского рода** со значением **лица** (то есть одушевленное), образованное от соответствующих наименований мужского рода. Я где-то что-то неправильно сформулировала? Поправьте.

Comment: потому что нет никаких значений лица. нет такой логики в русском. род слова говорит не о принадлежности к женщинам или мужчинам по полу, это вообще про другое.

Comment: Грубо говоря, маскулизмы вообще отсутствуют и феминитивы тоже, потому что большинство слов и названий не относятся к социальной ролевой игре. Разделение может быть только в узких словах обозначающих функцию: велосипедист, велосипедистка. Только в таком случае это равноправное деление по полу, а вот, например, охотник и охотница - это вообще разные слова. Охотник тот кто занимается охотой, название занятия связанного с понятием охота(охота не имеет пола, хотя род иногда нужен для согласования и других слов), а охотница - это не так, кто охотится на животных, а охотница до/на мужчин.

Comment: То есть получается уже переносное, а не прямое значение. Семантика искажает логику восприятия слова. Продавец - это тот кто продал товар, продавец товара - понятие. А продавщица - это тетя за прилавком. Нельзя сказать продавщица товара - это нелепица, то есть феминитив в данном случае не отражает абстракции слова продавать, а просто указывает что за прилавком стояла не женщина, а мужчина, не продавец, а продавщица. НО это совсем другая история. Феминитивы употребляются в частных случаях или когда идет речь о роли: актер/актриса, социально значимом действии, а не о понятии.

Comment: Род у самого понятия изменить не получится, потому что род определяет не логика пола.

Comment: Буратино, Вы опять не совсем внимательны! Охотник и охотница имеют два равноправных варианта значений (кроме корабля). Охотница с собакой. *Итальянская миллионерша, охотница на тигров, и ее археолог вскоре снова дали знать о себе* (Л. С. Ленч. Следы Марко Поло). Охотник до лошадей, до собак, до женщин. (http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%BE%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA)

Comment: не в русском языке, потому что род - это не пол, другой принцип в основе, не связанный с половым делением. "Мачиха моя, какъ уже прежде мною объявлено, надъ мѣру охотница была до веселостей" 1764г. "В скором времени почти весь гостиный двор узнали, что я великая охотница покупать нужные вещи" не охотница, а "охотница до", "охотница покупать". Нельзя сказать она охотница - это бессмыслица.

Comment: Ну Вы в словаре-то посмотрите! *Вячеслав Илларионович ужасный охотник до прекрасного пола...* (И. С. Тургенев. Два помещика (1847)). Мужчины уже почти двести лет тоже "переносны".

Comment: Римма Михайловна, мужской род может сохраняться, когда речь идет о мужчине персоне, само собой, но феминитив не имеет полноценной формы понятия, даже образованный. Это частный случай употребления слова, формы слова, не относящийся к общему понятию. Продавец - он и в документах продавец и за прилавком продавец. А продавщица - она продавщица только за прилавком, а в документах она - продавец.

Answer (score 0):

Придется написать похоже ответ, чтобы закрыть эту дебильную тему с феминитивами.

Те кто пытается делать из всего феминитивы(странно что они не делают маскулитивы, например, не пытаются образовывать слова мужского рода от роженица или мать..), не понимают(или специально делают вид что не понимают) логики словообразования русского языка.

Во-первых, нужно отметить, что какие-то горе лингвисты перевели гендер как пол, хотя это непереводимое слово, которое ближе к род, но не совсем. Физиологическая родословная  - это гендер, от слова ген и генетика. В этом смысле кто-то физиологически от Адама(может себя заявить так), кто-то может сказать что у него генетические предки или родственники приматы, кто-то скажет динозавры. Ну это пол беды, но это не имеет отношение к понятию ПОЛа от слова совсем. Нет гендера женщин или гендера мужчин - это бред. ПОЛа в понимании русской культуры и культуры два - М и Ж, хотя есть еще ребенок, тоже человек, но по сути половые признаки у него ярко не выражены, потому что секса у детей нет. А есть слово РОД, понятие такое в образовании слов русского языка, которое не имеет отношения к полу. Потому что у мужчин может быть нога и рука - женского рода, а может быть тело - среднего рода, эти части тела не делают его мужчиной или женщиной по полу. РОД - это такое деление необходимое для образования слова, относящееся к логике восприятия.

Все то, что называется феминитивами, это на самом деле непонимание языка в корне.

Продавец - это не мужик. Продавец - это понятие, причем юридическое, тот кто осуществляется продажу, сделку. Продавец товара.

А продавщица - это женщина, но за прилавком. Она осуществляет функцию продажи. Если функцию продажи осуществляет мужчина, то он не продавщица, а опять же продавец, просто у него не меняется род. Род необходим иногда, чтобы отметить некоторые частные моменты когда дело касается функции, социальной роли.

Так вот все эти феминитивы, относятся к узкому комплексу значений социальных ролей: артист/артистка, гитарист/гитаристка, ученик/ученица. Феминитив и сохранённая мужская форма - это указание, но не человека, а то что этот человек играет роль, человек **для**.

Скрипка - потому что скрипит, для скрипа. Труба - потому что трубит, рождает такой звук. Женский род связан с рождением следующего существительного или глагола. А вот Кларнет - он, мужской род, он не "кларнетит", он тоже "дудит", "трубит", "звенит". То есть уже проблема образовать от слов мужского рода связанные глаголы действия.

Меч - не то, что метит, а то, чем отмечают кого-то. Меч - наградное оружие, подарил меч. Либо меч - это вид оружия.

Сабля, катана, шашка - режет, поэтому отмечен функционал, потому и женский род.

Барабан - не барабанит сам, а в него стучат - барабанят.

А вот перепонная барабанка сама звук передает, сразу нужно слово функция, проводник.

Молот - сложное понятие. А молотят не молотом - а молотилкой.

**То есть если слово сопряжено с функцией, явной, то скорее всего у него будет форма женского рода. А если это сложное понятие, механизм или еще что - то мужского рода. Но это не имеет отношения к полу или к тому кто будет этим пользоваться мужчина или женщина.**

> Мужчина, притащи себя по мне, я до тебя охотница.Н. И. Новиков. 18в

> В скором времени почти весь гостиный двор узнали, что я великая охотница покупать нужные вещи.. Чулоков. 18в

Охотница - это "охотница до" и "охотница покупать". Нельзя сказать "она - охотница". Охотница до чего? Можно сказать "он - охотник". То есть у слова может сохранятся род который соответствует полу, но в определенных предложных случаях "до/для" - может образоваться женская форма, но это не значит, что "она стала охотницей", она может быть охотником или охотницей до/для.

Механизмы принято называть мужским родом, так как принцип работы: карданный вал, автомобиль. А функцию - женским: автомобиль для передвижение - машина.

Если речь идет о женщине учительнице в школе, то она может быть биологичка. Но если речь идет о профессии - то не важно, женщина или мужчина - это биолог. Биологичка не потому что женщина, а потому что учительница, функция учителя.

Поэтому такие феминитивы как директора - не имеют смысла. Губернатор - мужчина ли, женщина ли - это бюрократическая должность. Должность, кстати, женского рода и никого это не смущает. А губернаторша - это жена губернатора.

Речь идет об общем понятии и частном случае. Продавец - он и в документах продавец и за прилавком продавец. А продавщица - она продавщица только за прилавком, а в документах она - продавец.

Смешение общих понятий и случаев ведет только к разрушению вообще логики языка, а ни к какому равноправию женщин и мужчин. Нет тут никакого равноправия, потому что конкуренции нет.

Comment: Роженик... Без проблем образовывается :) Например, у морских коньков рожают мужики.

Comment: они не рожают увы, только выносят икру. не обеспечивают питание плода. но за роженика тебе уже сейчас можно нобелевку. давай еще от мать тоже - математик.

Comment: Меня надули на Youtube :(

Comment: угу, есть такое, самцы пип еще на спине икру выдерживают, там вообще жуткое зрелище.

Comment: Поверил, что они именно рожают. Самцы кого?

Comment: Самцы пипы суринамской.

Comment: Прикольно, не видел ничего подобного.

Comment: @Буратино Вижу еще одну "прикольность" — *А вот перепонная барабанка сама звук передает...* Это Вы так специально?

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова Точно так. Это выражение не режет слух именно потому, что образовано по правилам логики русского языка. Можно сказать и перепонка, а можно и барабанка. А вот перепонный барабан бы уже резало.